# How can I extract information from multiple pdf files to a text using java

Tags: java

I have multiple bank statements in pdf and I want to extract transactions that are over 30 dollars to a text file. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could try PDFBox, but honestly you need to make an effort and try something and come back if you encounter a *specific* problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at [Apache's PdfBox project](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).
I process my own bank statement using this library. It is fairly easy to use:

This is, how to extract text from a PDF document:

```
    public String getData(String fileName) throws IOException {
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
        PDDocument pdDoc;
        COSDocument cosDoc;
        ClassPathResource accountStatement = new ClassPathResource(fileName);

        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(accountStatement.getInputStream());
        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(2);
        String text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        pdDoc.close();
        return text;
}
```

The ClassPathResource class is from the Spring Framework, but you can replace it with anything similar.